Efficient way to reconstruct matrix from list of iterated dot products
Suppose I have a list of $n$ iterated dot products between an invertible $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and a length $n$ vector $x$
{A.x , MatrixPower[A,2].x, (*...*), MatrixPower[A,n].x}

In this case, x is known, and I would like to reconstruct A from the observed list of dot products.
As a MWE with small n=3 (note that I do not expect A to come from a GOE, I'm just using it here as a simple example to generate an invertible matrix):
SeedRandom[1234];
n = 3;

A = RandomVariate@GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[n];
x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], n];

results = MatrixPower[A, #] . x & /@ Range[n];


I can setup an objective function and NMinimize the flattened-out square residual:
obj[m_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := 
 With[{dotsList = MatrixPower[m, #] . x & /@ Range[n]},
  dotsList - results // Flatten // Norm
  ]

{resid, fittedMatrix} = 
   NMinimize[obj[m], 
    m \[Element] Matrices[{n, n}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
fittedMatrix = m /. fittedMatrix;

But this will get slow for much larger $n$.

I have a feeling there is a much more efficient way to do this, but my linear algebra knowledge isn't really deep enough to know what to do.

Just to be clear: $Ax$ is a row, not a column, of the constructed matrix?

$Ax$ is the result of A.x
, where x has ArrayDepth 1 and A is ArrayDepth 2 (but A is unknown). So the ith element of the list results is MatrixPower[A,i].x, and I want to find A from results and a known x. I might be misusing mathematical notation in my TeX equation ${Ax, AAx,..., A^nx}$ at the start which may be leading to confusion. I have replaced the TeX expression with a Mathematica expression that might make more sense.

You told me a bunch of stuff I knew, but you did not answer my question. {A.x, A.A.x} is a matrix with 2 rows and n (= Length[x]) columns. That is what you want? Usually, in a linear algebra setting, I think of $x$, $Ax$, etc. as column-matrix vectors and zip columns together to form a matrix. But not exclusively. I thought I'd ask for confirmation whether you wanted $A^k x$ to constitute the rows or the columns of the matrix.


{A.x, A.A.x} is a matrix with 2 rows and n (= Length[x]) columns.

Yes this is what I meant. Sorry, I started using Mathematica before I ever bothered even starting to learn linear algebra, so I get confused by the distinction between row and column vectors since they kind of feel the same to me, if that makes sense.

How about this? Arec is the reconstructed matrix.
Remarks:
$\bullet$ This code works only when $\{\boldsymbol{x}, A\boldsymbol{x}, A^2\boldsymbol{x}, \cdots, A^{n-1}\boldsymbol{x}\}$ are linearly independent. But this holds for generic choice of $A$ and $\boldsymbol{x}$.
$\bullet$ The list results (now slightly modified) starts from $\boldsymbol{x}$ so that result = $\{\boldsymbol{x}, A\boldsymbol{x}, A^2\boldsymbol{x}, \cdots, A^{n}\boldsymbol{x}\}$.
Idea:
Consider $\boldsymbol{x}$ as column vector.
Let us denote $\boldsymbol{x}^{(k)} = A^k \boldsymbol{x}$.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be the $n\times n$ matrices such that the each column corresponds to $\boldsymbol{x}^{(k)}$ as follows:
$$
X = (\boldsymbol{x}^{(0)}, \cdots,\boldsymbol{x}^{(n-1)}),\qquad
Y = (\boldsymbol{x}^{(1)}, \cdots,\boldsymbol{x}^{(n)}).
$$
Then, the relation
$$
A \boldsymbol{x}^{(k)}= \boldsymbol{x}^{(k+1)}\qquad (k=0,1,2,\cdots,n-1)
$$
is equivalent to
$$
AX=Y.
$$
Therefore, if $X$ is invertible, we can reconstruct $A$ as $A=YX^{-1}$.
As @MichelE2 commented, MMA usually represents matrix as a collection of row vectors (while A.x is interpreted as usual $A\boldsymbol{x}$), so we have to be careful about the ordering of matrix product and Transpose is needed to get the right result.
SeedRandom[1234];
n = 6;

A = RandomVariate@GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[n];
x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], n];

results = NestList[A . # &, x, n];

Arec = Transpose[Inverse[Most[results]] . Rest[results]];

A // MatrixForm


Arec // MatrixForm


Max@Abs@Flatten[A - Arec]

(* 7.37743*10^-13 *)


That works for me! I can't say I understand Transpose[Inverse[Most[results]] . Rest[results]] (I guess it is transposed least squares solution to Most[results].something == Rest[results]? ) but I will try to get a better feeling for it. I probably should start reading a linear algebra book because it keeps popping up in work I'm doing now, and I never took a linear algebra course in undergrad :D

@ydd I added in my answer some explanation why the code can reconstruct $A$.  The idea is very simple.

@A.Kato that is such a neat approach with clear explanation

@ubpdqn Thank you. Teaching linear algebra is my bread and butter, after all. (^_^)

It works when the minimal polynomial agrees with the characteristic polynomial (equiv, matrix is diagonalizable if I'm thinking clearly).
